# If $E''$ is the bidual of E. Why do we have $E \subset E''$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that it does exist a canonical injection $J:E \rightarrow E''$ such that $\forall$ $x\in E$  and $\forall$ $f \in E'$  we have $\langle Jx,f\rangle_{E'',E'}=\langle f,x \rangle _{E',E}$ and, of course, it may happen that $J$ is not surjective from $E$ onto $E''$.

Brezis, in "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" pag.9, says that it is convenient to identify $E$ with a subspace of $E''$ and, at pag 62,  $E \subset E''$.

How can be this true? $E''$ is the dual of $E'$ that is the dual of $E$, how can I say that an element of $E$ is also an element of $E''$?

Could anyone help me? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The trick is the word "identify".  In the same way we "identify" $\mathbb Z$ with a subset of $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is not a subset of $E''$. It is a common practice to identify normed linear  spaces that are isometrically isomorphic. $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $E''$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! But how can I say the topology $\sigma(E',E)$ is coarser than the topology $\sigma(E',E'')$ using this fact?

Comment: Any $x \in E$ leads to an $x'' \in E"$ defined by $x''(x')=x'(x)$. Use this and basic neighborhoods in the topologies to see immediately that $\sigma (E',E)$ is coarser than $\sigma (E',E'')$

Comment: If : $\phi_{x} (f) = f(x)$ and $\phi_{x''} (f) = x''(f)$ . Every $U$ open in $\sigma(E',E)$ can we be written as:
 $U=\cup_{arbitrary}\cap_{finite} \phi ^{-1}_{x}(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, $\phi_{x}^{-1}(\omega)=${$f \in E' : \langle f,x \rangle \in \omega $} and we know that  $\forall x \in E$  there exists $x''$ such that for any $x' \in E'$ :  $x''(x')=x'(x)$ so I can write $\phi_{x}^{-1}(\omega)=${$f \in E' : \langle x'',f \rangle \in \omega $} and so $U$ should be also open in $\sigma(E',E'')$.
I am not sure it is okay , can you give me some hint? Thank you!!

Comment: I've solved it! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is always an identification understood, even when you see $E \subset E''$. The vector spaces $E$ and $E''$ are different, they contain elements of different nature, so one cannot be a subset of the other from a pure set theoretical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

***Reply to the Post itself:***

Another way of looking at this is considering the canonical injection $J: E \to E''$ defined as $J(x)(f) = f(x) \equiv \phi_x(f)$ for all $x \in E$ and $f \in E'$. Then $J(E) \subseteq E''$ (the meaning of $E \subseteq E''$: $E$ is "identified" through the canonical injection $J$ as $J(E)$. $J$ is an isomorphism from $E$ to $J(E)$!).

***In Regards to the comment section in the other replies:***

Note $\sigma(E', E'')$ is the (weakest) topology on $E'$ such that **all** elements in $E''$ (i.e. linear strongly continuous functionals on $E'$) is continuous in the general topological sense.

On the other hand, $\sigma(E', E)$ is the **weakest** topology on $E'$ such that all element in $J(E)$ is topologically continuous.

Since any element in $J(E)$ is an element of $E''$ as $J(E) \subseteq E''$, we know the topology $\sigma(E', E'')$ **is a topology that makes all element in $J(E)$ topologically continuous.** As $\sigma(E', E)$ is the **weakest (most economical)** topology by definition to make all element in $J(E)$ topologically continuous, we must have $\sigma(E', E) \subseteq \sigma(E', E'')$. That is, $\sigma(E', E)$ to be weaker/coarser than $\sigma(E', E'')$.